# Using Dynamics 365 Web API with VBA, do I have to use the primary key to update a record?

Tags: vba, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, webapi

I am using Dynamics 365 Web API with VBA to update a specific entity record. However, I don't have the primary key GUID but I do have another a combination of other field values that would identify a unique record. Is there a way to change the `Request.Resource` line to use the other fields?

This code works if I provide the specific primary key GUID but I won't have the GUID when it needs to be updated.

```
Dim crm As New crm
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Dim Response As WebResponse
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Request.Resource = "productpricelevels(F01E6888-7643-EE11-BDF4-00224808D9DA)"  
Request.Format = WebFormat.Json
Request.ResponseFormat = Json
Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPatch

'== field to update
dict.Add "amount", 4

Request.Body = WebHelpers.ConvertToJson(dict)

' Response from query
Set Response = crm.Query(Request)

If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.NoContent Then
    Debug.Print ("Success")
    ...
```

Comment: The only other option besides the entity ID (GUID) is to use a defined **alternate key** - if any of those are defined on your entity in question

Comment: Can you query the GUID and then use that for the update?

Comment: upvoted, first time I see a Dataverse Web API used in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *should* be possible via `alternate keys` which you have to define yourself.

1. Create the Key in Dataverse using a unique combination of columns
2. Wait for the async job to complete
3. Reference your record

It should look like this:

```
Request.Resource = "productpricelevels(name='fish and chips',fishtype='hoki')"
```

Reference: [Use an alternate key to reference a record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/use-alternate-key-reference-record?tabs=webapi)